# Why does updateOne() with $pull give an error?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In my collection of Users each user has a friends array.

I'm trying to remove a single element from the array using the friendId property inside each element as a filter to find the correct element, my Schema's are:

My user collection schema:

```
{ 
  googleId: String,
  profile: Object,
  friends: [friendshipSchema],
}
```

My friendshipSchema:

```
    { 
      friendId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
      confirmed: { type: Boolean, default: false },
      status: String,
    }
```

my query to my DB looks like:

```
    console.log("req.body.params.id", req.body.params.id, "req.user.id", req.user.id);
    try {
      await Users.updateOne({
        _id: req.user._id,
        $pull: { friends: { friendId: req.body.params.id } },
      });
      await Users.updateOne({
        _id: req.body.params.id,
        $pull: { friends: { friendId: req.user._id } },
      });
      res.send("collections updated");
    }
```

I get this error in return:

```
MongoError: Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id'

Code: 66
```

while testing with different users this code works with one of the users in the collection but not any of the others, the Schema's are the same on all Users.

Comment: You seem to be passing both _id and $pull as updates, where the _id condition must be a lookup and the $pull must be update. Review the documentation for the correct syntax to use.

Comment: Yes That was the issue, when the filter and update portions are wrapped with seperate   { } it worked as expected